# Input string was not in a correct format at dropdownlist from websvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm trying to integrate my self-created web service together with my web-application. In my websvc, i created a method like below.

```
public double CarTaxwithOMV(int coetax)
    { 
        double coe = coetax;

        if (coetax == 1)
        {
            coe = 1.3;
        }
        else if (coetax == 2)
        {
            coe=1.1;
        }
        else if (coetax == 3)
        {
            coe = 1;
        }
}
```

Then in my web-application i tried to call the values above in my web-application

```
int coe = Convert.ToInt32("DropDownList1.SelectedValue");

double totalcost = tc.CarTaxwithOMV(coe);

lblinfo.Text = "Your total car tax for the above information is " + totalcost + ".";
```

In my aspx page, i have assigned a value with my dropdownlist options.

```
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">COEs obtained from May 2002 to February 2004 tender exercises</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">COEs obtained from March 2004 to February 2008 tender exercises.</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">COEs obtained from March 2008 onwards tender exercises.</asp:ListItem>
```

The value i declare in both my websvc and aspx page are all in integer. However when i tried to call and obtain the value from the websvc method to my web application i got this error at the dropdownlist

```
Input string was not in a correct format
```

Does anyone have any idea how does this error come from ?

Comment: remove quatation from this line   Convert.ToInt32("DropDownList1.SelectedValue");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are trying to convert string to integer.

your line

```
int coe = Convert.ToInt32("DropDownList1.SelectedValue");
```

should be

```
int coe = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
```

on a side note i would also recommend that you use [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of convert.ToInt32

Answer (score 0):

You didn't return a value from `CarTaxwithOMV` method. And also 
`Convert.ToInt32("DropDownList1.SelectedValue");` Should be

```
Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
```

You are trying to convert a string value instead of a integer..